# php performance for get and load avatar image

Tags: php, performance

I add/upload image avatar using `md5` user id and `file_put_contents` like this:

```
$image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);
$image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);
$data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);
$imageName = md5(Session::get('user_id')) . '.png';
file_put_contents(Config::get('PATH_UPLOAD') . '/' .      Session::get('user_id') . '/' . $imageName, $data);
```

with this method I add only one image avatar for each user into my directory with this structure :

```
public
    upload
      images
        avatar
             77  <-- userID
               d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.png
```

Now I have two way for get image.

1. add image name/type into database and retrieve data from database and show in view page
2. get image name with session unique userId from file folder/directory without database

which way is better for performance(fast load)?!

Comment: Have you tried it and see what the difference is?

Comment: @NigelRen: no, not tested.